Error de inserción de datos en SQL SV
Tengo un problema al tratar de insertar datos en sql sv, en las tablas donde ingreso datos, paran cambiando los campos donde no reconoce los valores. Adjunto imágenes cuando cargo los datos en las tablas y no cargan los campos donde los reconoce como vacíos (no guardan nada).


String insertRefraccion = "INSERT INTO REFRACCION (HISTORIAL_ID, CONSULTA_ID, ESFERA_OD, CILINDRO_OD, EJE_OD, DIP_OD, ESFERA_OI, CILINDRO_OI, EJE_OI, DIP_OI, ADICION_CERCA) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try (PreparedStatement stmtInsert = con.prepareStatement(insertRefraccion)) {
        stmtInsert.setString(1, historialId);
        stmtInsert.setInt(2, consultaId);
        
        stmtInsert.setFloat(3, Float.parseFloat(refraccionOD.getValueAt(0, 0).toString()));
        stmtInsert.setFloat(4, Float.parseFloat(refraccionOD.getValueAt(0, 1).toString()));
        stmtInsert.setFloat(5, Float.parseFloat(refraccionOD.getValueAt(0, 2).toString()));
        stmtInsert.setFloat(6, Float.parseFloat(refraccionOD.getValueAt(0, 3).toString()));

        stmtInsert.setFloat(7, Float.parseFloat(refraccionOI.getValueAt(0, 0).toString()));
        stmtInsert.setFloat(8, Float.parseFloat(refraccionOI.getValueAt(0, 1).toString()));
        stmtInsert.setFloat(9, Float.parseFloat(refraccionOI.getValueAt(0, 2).toString()));
        stmtInsert.setFloat(10, Float.parseFloat(refraccionOI.getValueAt(0, 3).toString()));
        
        stmtInsert.setFloat(11, Float.parseFloat(adicionCercaField.getText()));
        
        stmtInsert.executeUpdate();
    }

    String insertFondoOjo = "INSERT INTO FONDO_OJO (HISTORIAL_ID, CONSULTA_ID, COPA_DISCO_OD, VASOS_RENALES_OD, MACULA_OD, RETINA_OD, MEDIOS_OD, COPA_DISCO_OI, VASOS_RENALES_OI, MACULA_OI, RETINA_OI, MEDIOS_OI) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try (PreparedStatement stmtInsert = con.prepareStatement(insertFondoOjo)) {
        stmtInsert.setString(1, historialId);
        stmtInsert.setInt(2, consultaId);
        
        stmtInsert.setString(3, fondoOjoOD.getValueAt(0, 0).toString());
        stmtInsert.setString(4, fondoOjoOD.getValueAt(0, 1).toString());
        stmtInsert.setString(5, fondoOjoOD.getValueAt(0, 2).toString());
        stmtInsert.setString(6, fondoOjoOD.getValueAt(0, 3).toString());
        stmtInsert.setString(7, fondoOjoOD.getValueAt(0, 4).toString());
        
        stmtInsert.setString(8, fondoOjoOI.getValueAt(0, 0).toString());
        stmtInsert.setString(9, fondoOjoOI.getValueAt(0, 1).toString());
        stmtInsert.setString(10, fondoOjoOI.getValueAt(0, 2).toString());
        stmtInsert.setString(11, fondoOjoOI.getValueAt(0, 3).toString());
        stmtInsert.setString(12, fondoOjoOI.getValueAt(0, 4).toString());
        
        stmtInsert.executeUpdate();
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Historial clínico guardado exitosamente.");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar el historial clínico: " + e.getMessage());
}

}

Tienes try sin catch, como vas a saber que errores ocurren durante la ejecución ??

Hola Alejandro. Aparte de que como señala @Excorpion, tienes un try... sin catch, la redacción de la pregunta no se entiende: ¿Qué es sql sv? ¿Qué quieres decir con: en las tablas donde ingreso datos, paran cambiando los campos donde no reconoce los valores? ¿Qué significa: cuando cargo los datos en las tablas y no cargan los campos donde los reconoce como vacíos (no guardan nada)? Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para clarificar tu problema añadiendo además eventuales  mensajes de error en el código.

Añadiste un fragmento de catch, pero aún asi dejaste los otros try sin catch igual. Tienes que separar ambas consultas, son procesos independientes, quizás tu problema radica en eso, tratas de hacer 2 al mismo tiempo.

@Excorpion no necesariamente tienen por qué ser procesos independientes, eso depende de las reglas de negocio de la aplicación. Pueden también ser dependientes unos de otros. En ese caso, lo recomendable sería hacer ambas inserciones dentro de un solo bloque usando transacciones, así, si alguno de los INSERT da problemas, se hace un rollBack para invalidar el otro y no hay inconsistencia en los datos. Cabe decir que si son independientes, también se puede usar transacciones.

Ja, yo pensaba hacer 2

Hay 2 opciones: no estás enviando los datos correctamente y eso lo verificas con el debugger, la otra opción es que esté generando un error, pero no sabemos cual es. Para ayudarte con el error, necesitamos conocer el error.
